# PHP script to download json file and display data

Tags: php, beginner, json

display.php:

```
<?php
include "funtc.php";
updater();
$token = json_decode(file_get_contents('wp-content/themes/World-of-Warcraft-New/includes/token.json'));//<--open data file
$data = $token->update->NA->formatted;//<--store primary object 
if(!isset($data, $data->buy,$data->{'24min'},$data->{'24max'},$data->timeToSell,$data->updated)){ //<-- check each object property for data
unset ($token);//<-- If false clear variable
$old = json_decode(file_get_contents('wp-content/themes/World-of-Warcraft-New/includes/back.json'));//<--open backup data file
$data = $old->update->NA->formatted;
badfile();
}
?>

<!-- Start WOW token data import--> 
    <div id="tokenbox">
            <p class="gold">Buy:&nbsp;<?php echo chop($data->buy,"g"); ?></p>
            <p>24-hour change:&nbsp;<?php echo chop($data->{'24min'},"g"); ?><span class="gold">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> - <?php echo chop($data->{'24max'},"g"); ?><span class="gold">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></p>
            <p>Time To Sell:&nbsp;<?php echo chop($data->timeToSell,"g"); ?></p>
            <p>Updated:&nbsp;<?php echo chop($data->updated,"EDT"); ?> <br><a  href="https://wowtoken.info">WOWToken</a></p>
    </div>
<!-- End WOW token data import-->
```

This is the file that is use read json file and display data. I used the "!isset" function to check if all the object property's are vaild and have data because the file creator tends to change the file often. In the event that the format does change there is backup file that script can use to display the lasted use data file before the new was grabbed.

funtc.php:

```
//updater
function updater(){
    $now = strtotime('now'); //<--store current unix timestamp
    $stat = json_decode(file_get_contents('wp-content/themes/World-of-Warcraft-New/includes/stat.json'),true);//<--open updater status file
    $opts =stream_context_create(array( 'http' => array( 'timeout' =>3, 'user_agent'=> "The WarCraft Call Board - http://swcallboard.com")));
    if ($now > $stat['update'] && $stat['heath']=="alive" ){// <--check if currnet timestamp is greater than last updated timestamp and if no errors recorded
        $file = file_get_contents("https://wowtoken.info/wowtoken.json", 0, $opts); //<--grab remote file if check clears 
        if($file){
            rename("wp-content/themes/World-of-Warcraft-New/includes/token.json", "wp-content/themes/World-of-Warcraft-New/includes/back.json");//<-creates backup file
            file_put_contents("wp-content/themes/World-of-Warcraft-New/includes/token.json",$file );//<--writes remote file data to local file
            $stat['update']= strtotime('+20 minute');//<-- sets the "update" value of status file to 20mins. from now
            file_put_contents("wp-content/themes/World-of-Warcraft-New/includes/stat.json",json_encode($stat));//<--writes new values to status file
            }
    } 
} 

//erorr catchers

// for general errors
function bad($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
$stat = json_decode(file_get_contents('wp-content/themes/World-of-Warcraft-New/includes/stat.json'),true);//<--open updater status file
    if ($stat['heath']=="alive" ){//<-- check status file if there is a error already recorded
    $stat['heath']= "dead";//<-- set status value to disable updater
    file_put_contents("wp-content/themes/World-of-Warcraft-New/includes/stat.json",json_encode($stat));//<-- writes new values to status file
    error_log("Error: [$errno] $errstr $errfile $errline",1,
    "comentss@swcallboard.com","From: errorlog@swcallboard.com");//<-- email error report
    }
}

set_error_handler("bad");

// for file read errors that could be cuased by file format changes
function badfile(){
    $stat = json_decode(file_get_contents('wp-content/themes/World-of-Warcraft-New/includes/stat.json'),true);
    if ($stat['heath']=="alive" ){
        $stat['heath']= "dead";
        file_put_contents("wp-content/themes/World-of-Warcraft-New/includes/stat.json",json_encode($stat));
        copy("wp-content/themes/World-of-Warcraft-New/includes/back.json","wp-content/themes/World-of-Warcraft-New/includes/token.json");
        error_log("Error: [8] Bad File, updater stopped.",1,
        "comentss@swcallboard.com","From: errorlog@swcallboard.com");
    }

}
?>
```

This the functions file that handles the updating of the data file and error that happen when the script is running. The updater uses a unix time stamp form "strtotime" to make sure that the updater only connects to remote server every twenty minutes. The time stamp and error or "health" state of the script are stored in a status file. The other function of the updater is to create a back of current data file before it is overwritten with new data. 
I have have been using this script for a few months now and it seem to work fine but there are tow things I could not get around:

1. FGC downloads the whole file, which includes the current data plus historical data and could not figure out how to grab only the needed data without breaking the json file. I know that there is the "maxlen" parameter that lets you set how much of the data FGC should read but the size and length of the file changed constantly, so it seem like not an option.
2. A few times the error log reporter has sent a message that says:
   "trying to get property of non-object in display.php 5". I have looked over both the display.php and token.json files and have not found a problem in either of the files. The last time this happen was on Dec. 1 but no problems reported since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json download is likely all or nothing. Partial content couldn't be parsed by the client. The error message may be for line 5:

```
if(!isset($data, $data->buy,$data->{'24min'},$data->{'24max'},$data->timeToSell,$data->updated)){ //<-- check each object property for data
```

The object couldn't be parsed it sounds like.